# Boiling Point trend

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, boiling-point

Why does group 13 and 14 show reverse the trend of boiling point? In other groups, boiling point increases down the group but here it decreases.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/trend-in-the-melting-point-down-the-group

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35716/why-there-is-an-exception-in-melting-and-boiling-point-in-p-block