# Why are the melting points of Sb and Bi lower than that of As?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, melting-point

My book says it has something to do with the inert pair effect. And unlike As, Sb and Bi tend to form 3 covalent bonds rather than 5. I don't understand what's really going on here.

Comment: see this:http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/trend-in-the-melting-point-down-the-group